# Linking first and second level composite primary keys

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to create a new database with a hierarchical structure of two many-to-many tables using composite keys. Unfortunately the creation of tables fails stating that the `foreign keys do not match`:

**Here a simplified Structure of the sql query:**

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    a_ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    a_name char(100)
);

CREATE TABLE b(
    b_ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    b_name char(100)
);

CREATE TABLE c(
    c_ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
    c_name char(250),
);

-- First refering table
CREATE TABLE b_c(
    b_ID INT references b ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    c_ID INT references c ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_ID, c_ID)
);
-- Second higher level combining 
CREATE TABLE full(
    b_c_ID INT references b_c ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    a_ID INT references a ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_c_ID, a_ID)
);
```

The creation of the last table fails. 
Am I missing something here or is it impossible to refer to a composite primary key in just another composition?
Any comments?

Comment: If a pk is composite (i.e. 2 columns), the foreign key constraint needs to have 2 columns as well.

Comment: Irrelevant but you shouldn't name your table `full`. That's a SQL keyword and it will only give you trouble.

Comment: Yes. Of course my names were just abbreviated examples

Comment: Do you mind removing the "hierarchical" from the title? That usualy refers to special, self-referential design and related queries. It doesn't appear related to your case (you probably have an hierarchy of tables, as it is clear from the wording, i.e. first, second level - but that is not relevant to the question asked.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 2 columns in the foreign key constraint, to refer to a table with  2 columns in the primary key:

```
-- Second higher level combining 
CREATE TABLE full_b_c(
    b_ID INT NOT NULL,
    c_ID INT NOT NULL,
    a_ID INT NOT NULL references a ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    PRIMARY KEY (b_ID, c_ID, a_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (b_ID, c_ID) 
      references b_c (b_ID, c_ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Comment: Great Thanks. And again I learned something new.